# Why does this JavaScript function always returns 'undefined' – and how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap with application preferences plugin and trying to make a helper function to get a value from it. However the function is not returning a correct value. I know this has to do with asynchronous thingy but unfortunately I don't know how to fix it. (I've tried to search help here, and found little, and tried to implement it in helper method)

What I want to achieve is:

```
function populateList() {
    var a = 1;

    var number = getSettingFromApplicationPreferences('number');
    // number is always undefined

    var letter = getSettingFromApplicationPreferences('letter');
    // letter is always undefined

    number = (number) ? number : 1;
    letter = (letter) ? letter : 'b';

    // Here I'll do some DOM manipulation and use 'number' and 'letter' on it, and 
    // define new variables based on 'number' and 'letter'

}
```

here's the helper function that I need help with:

```
function getSettingFromApplicationPreferences(setting) {

    var x = (function () {
        window.plugins.applicationPreferences.get(
            // setting
            setting, 
            // success callback
            function(returnValue) {
                console.log(setting + ': ' + returnValue);
                return returnValue;
            },
            // error callback
            function(error) {
                alert("Failed to get a setting: " + error);
                return false;
            }
        );
    })();

    return x;   
}
```

**Question**
How is it possible to return the 'returnValue' from application preferences with that helper function?

Comment: What a long `function` name! Don't do that because you might type it in one letter wrong and it will give you a headache...

Comment: The success and error callbacks are invoked **asynchronously** by the runtime environment, which will ignore return values (for most things).

Comment: Is the whole immediate-execution function thing because you were trying to pretend it wasn't asynch or something? Otherwise that's a little confusing.

Comment: yes, beacause i thought it would make it non-async... not a guru in js :(

Comment: why? because `b` have the value undefined, fix? don't give `b` the undefined value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, your callback doesn't actually set a value for x. So, you're going to have some other way to do whatever you're doing, because return values will not work.

Comment: Yup. So put the `populateList` function inside to the `function(returnValue)` function.

Comment: that's NOT an option because I need multiple setting values as variables so there would be way too many nesting

Comment: @micadelli - You *have* to do that.

Comment: Meant that putting `populateList` inside success callback isn't an option

Comment: Define a PopulateListWithParam function, call that inside the callback with returnValue like: PopulateListWithParam(returnValue)

Comment: @micadelli Regarding too much nesting: this is a very real problem but there are solutions. Asynchronous style requires a bit of a gear shift before it becomes natural. See [here](https://github.com/caolan/async) for one example of how to make the nesting more manageable.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an asynchronous function incorrectly, you cannot assign like you are because the function hasn't returned yet and so you get an undefined. You need to use a callback function instead.

That means that inside the success function you would do whatever you need to do with the "returnValue".

Comment: your comment on Dhaivat Pandya's answer makes some sense to me... but i've updated the code example to clarify the problem